# PhotoSwipe.com gallery picture alignment

Tags: css, photoswipe

I'm trying to get PhotoSwipe gallery to line-up my pictures

Link to the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOvZeL

Is there any other way than adding a absolute height attribute to the figure-tag?
Or any way that the "row height" is variable (as high as the highest imange)?

**Right now it looks like that:**

http://s27.postimg.org/x4eyro4gj/Capture.png

**And here is what I'm expecting:**

http://s10.postimg.org/d03qh5tyx/Untitled.png

html

```
  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>...
</div>
```

css:

```
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.my-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.my-gallery figure {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.my-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set fix `height` to `.my-gallery figure`  class.

```js
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

  // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
  // (children of gallerySelector)
  var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
    var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
      numNodes = thumbElements.length,
      items = [],
      figureEl,
      linkEl,
      size,
      item;

    for (var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

      figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

      // include only element nodes 
      if (figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
        continue;
      }

      linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

      size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

      // create slide object
      item = {
        src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
        h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
      };

      if (figureEl.children.length > 1) {
        // <figcaption> content
        item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML;
      }

      if (linkEl.children.length > 0) {
        // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
        item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
      }

      item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
      items.push(item);
    }

    return items;
  };

  // find nearest parent element
  var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
    return el && (fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn));
  };

  // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
  var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

    var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // find root element of slide
    var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
      return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
    });

    if (!clickedListItem) {
      return;
    }

    // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
    // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
    var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
      childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
      numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
      nodeIndex = 0,
      index;

    for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
      if (childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) {
        continue;
      }

      if (childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
        index = nodeIndex;
        break;
      }
      nodeIndex++;
    }

    if (index >= 0) {
      // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
      openPhotoSwipe(index, clickedGallery);
    }
    return false;
  };

  // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
  var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
      params = {};

    if (hash.length < 5) {
      return params;
    }

    var vars = hash.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      if (!vars[i]) {
        continue;
      }
      var pair = vars[i].split('=');
      if (pair.length < 2) {
        continue;
      }
      params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    if (params.gid) {
      params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
    }

    return params;
  };

  var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
      gallery,
      options,
      items;

    items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

    // define options (if needed)
    options = {

      // define gallery index (for URL)
      galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

      getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
        // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
        var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
          pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
          rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();

        return {
          x: rect.left,
          y: rect.top + pageYScroll,
          w: rect.width
        };
      }

    };

    // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
    if (fromURL) {
      if (options.galleryPIDs) {
        // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
        // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
          if (items[j].pid == index) {
            options.index = j;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        // in URL indexes start from 1
        options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
      }
    } else {
      options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
    }

    // exit if index not found
    if (isNaN(options.index)) {
      return;
    }

    if (disableAnimation) {
      options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
    }

    // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
    gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
  };

  // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
  var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll(gallerySelector);

  for (var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i + 1);
    galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
  }

  // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
  var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
  if (hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
    openPhotoSwipe(hashData.pid, galleryElements[hashData.gid - 1], true, true);
  }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

```css
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.my-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.my-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>

  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
  </figure>


</div>


<!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

  <!-- Background of PhotoSwipe. 
         It's a separate element, as animating opacity is faster than rgba(). -->
  <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

  <!-- Slides wrapper with overflow:hidden. -->
  <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

    <!-- Container that holds slides. PhotoSwipe keeps only 3 slides in DOM to save memory. -->
    <!-- don't modify these 3 pswp__item elements, data is added later on. -->
    <div class="pswp__container">
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Default (PhotoSwipeUI_Default) interface on top of sliding area. Can be changed. -->
    <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

      <div class="pswp__top-bar">

        <!--  Controls are self-explanatory. Order can be changed. -->

        <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

        <!-- Preloader demo http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/yyBWoR -->
        <!-- element will get class pswp__preloader--active when preloader is running -->
        <div class="pswp__preloader">
          <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
            <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
              <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
        <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div>
      </div>

      <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
      </button>

      <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
      </button>

      <div class="pswp__caption">
        <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way that I do not have to set a absolute size? (see my edit on the question - I allready knew this option, but I forgot to add it to my question)